# Load in a script at a previous folder

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on my website, I want to include a script from an other folder.
I got 3 folders
Root:

- images
- js
- project <-- files index.html

If im working in a project, I want to include a js from the folder in js. How to do dis?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
```

?

How to import from a parent directory

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into? Using [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) should be your first stop.

Comment: Really not clear what your problem is

Comment: @cherlieft How to import from a parent directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe should work, if the relative path is correct.

A common pattern when you wish to use an absolute path is to set an assets path and use that.

```
<?php
$js_path = '/some/path/js/';
?>

<script src="<? echo $js_path . 'my_js.js'; ?>">
```

Comment: I mean, I need to use a file in a other dir, I need to go a folder up

Comment: @wortel538 I understand that. I only meant that if what your are doing is not working then check your actual structure or you can use that pattern. Also, remember that if the physical location of your script may not be the location it is run from when included. For instance, if your file structure has `project/templates` or something the `../js/*.js` path may not be correct compared to the location the file is **run** from. Adding a `is_file()` or `is_readable()` may help you find out what is going on.